# Find the highest number of occurences in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

Given this table:

Order
custName description to_char(price)
A        desa $14
B        desb $14
C        desc $21
D        desd $65
E        dese $21
F        desf  $78
G        desg $14
H        desh $21

I am trying to display the whole row where prices have the highest occurances, in this case $14 and $21

I believe there needs to be a subquery. So i started out with this:

```
select max(count(price))  
from orders  
group by price
```

which gives me 3.

after some time i didn't think that was helpful. i believe i needed the value 14 and 21 rather the the count so i can put that in the where clause. but I'm stuck how to display that. any help?

UPDATE: So I got it to query the 14 and 21 from this

```
    select price
    from orders
    group by price
    having (count(price)) in
    (select max(count(price))
    from orders
    group by price)
```

but i need it to display the custname and description column which i get an error:

```
select custname, description, price
from orders
group by price
having (count(price)) in
(select max(count(price))
from orders
group by price)

SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

any help on this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: is your answer helping my initial question or the update question with the error? i tried using your but i get some errors too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are pretty close. Since HAVING operates on the GROUPed result set, try

```
HAVING COUNT(price) IN
```

or

```
HAVING COUNT(price) =
```

replacing your current line.

Comment: i messed around with it and got the same thing. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question as oracle, you can use [windowing functions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10736/analysis.htm#i1006709) to get aggregate and detail data within the same query.

```
SELECT   COUNT (price) OVER (PARTITION BY price) count_at_this_price, 
         o.* 
from orders o 
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee, count(employee)
from work
group by employee
having count(employee) =
( select max(cnt) from
( select employee, count(employee cnt
from work
group by employee
)
);
```

[Reference](http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1630661-max-count-sum.html)

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like

```
select * from orders where price in (select top 2 price from orders group by price order by price desc)
```

I'm not sure of limiting results in Oracle, in SQL Server is top, maybe you should use limit.

Comment: this is homework and i've never learned the top function yet (but helpful in the future) so i don't think i can use it. thanks though!

Comment: TOP is not available in Oracle.  It is available in SQL Server and probably a few other databases